# Attributed string with NSLinkAttribute does not render on the iPhone

Tags: ios, ios7, nsstring, uitextview, nsattributedstring

We have an attributed string with 3 components, two are basic strings, the third is a link. The string is being rendered by a UITextView.  Strangely, the link is invisible on the iPhone, yet renders fine on the iPad.  The behavior is consistent regardless of simulator or actual phone.

Attempting to change the color of the link has no effect.  Interestingly, setting the underline color will show the underline... but the text is still invisible.

iOS 7, Xcode 5

Here is our code:

```
// put together our text for the about view, includes link to Facebook
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Sansation_Bold_Italic" size:aboutText.font.pointSize];
UIFont *linkFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Sansation_Italic" size:aboutText.font.pointSize];
NSMutableDictionary* linkAttributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[linkAttributes setObject:@"https://www.facebook.com/App" forKey:NSLinkAttributeName];
[linkAttributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] forKey:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName];
[linkAttributes setObject:[UIColor blueColor] forKey:NSStrokeColorAttributeName];
[linkAttributes setObject:[UIColor blueColor] forKey:NSUnderlineColorAttributeName];
[linkAttributes setObject:linkFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSAttributedString* link = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Facebook" attributes:linkAttributes];
NSMutableAttributedString* mas = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"ABOUTMSG1", nil)];
[mas appendAttributedString:link];
[mas appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"ABOUTMSG2", nil)]];
[aboutText setAttributedText:mas];
```

iPhone

[image: iPhone result]

iPad

[image: iPad result]

Any thoughts on why the link is not rendering on the iPhone?

Comment: what happens if you try a different font, just for testing?

Comment: Great idea!  Was expecting to learn something new, but alas, the results were the same.  Used both the system font and bold system font and assigned them to the Attributed string as well as to the UITextView itself.  Bummmer, really thought you were on to something there.

Comment: something else I've noticed is that you don't do anything with the first line of your code snippet, the "`font`" object.  Maybe you should try adding that to the attributed strings you use when setting the label to "`ABOUTMSG1`".

Comment: I actually had that in there to set the UITextView later, after adding the attributed string...  I will try setting that at the Attributed String level than at the View level, but I think I arrived at that after trying a few iterations.

Comment: Still no good... thought maybe that having attributed strings mixed with basic strings was no good... but that wasn't the case.  Annoying.

Answer (score 0):

For some weird reason the color appears to be `ClClear.

In any case, if you set the `linkTextAttributes` of your `UITextView` to empty

> (`linkTextAttributes = [:]` in **Swift**)

Then you can set custom color to your link as for any other text.